# Prove that MGF defined on an open set is infinitely differentiable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, moment-generating-functions

I am doing an exercise in the book "Applied Stochastic Analysis" by E-Li-Vanden-Eijnden, and I meet this problem (on Page 26):

> (Exercise 1.19) Prove that if the moment generating function $M_X(t)$ can be defined
> on an open set $U$, then $M_X(t)\in C^{\infty}(U)$.

Here is my approach:

Use Taylor's expansion at $t=t_0$,
$$\frac{1}{t}\mathbb{E}[e^{(t_0+t)X}-e^{t_0X}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{t_0X}X]+o(t)\mathbb{E}[e^{t_0X}]$$
Let $t\to 0$,
$$\frac{d}{dt}M_X(0)=\mathbb{E}[e^{t_0X}X]$$
Repeat differentiation $n$ times,
$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}M_X(0)=\mathbb{E}[e^{t_0X}X^n]$$
Since $n$ is arbitrary, as $n\to\infty$, we prove the claim.

Can anyone help me check whether my approach is valid? I'm not quite confident, since the exercise allows only on open sets. Alternative approaches are also fine. Thank you.

**Edit:**
OKay, I think I figure this out. Choose $U=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. For $|t|<\epsilon$,
$$\frac{|t|^n|X|^n}{n!}\leq e^{t|X|}\leq e^{tX}+e^{-tX}<\infty$$
and since
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(tX)^k}{k!}\right|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{|tX|^k}{k!}\leq e^{|tX|}\leq e^{tX}+e^{-tX}$$
By dominated convergence theorem, $$M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tX)^k}{k!}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}\mathbb{E}[X^k]$$
$M_X(t)$ coincides with the power series on $U=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, and hence it is infinitely differentiable on $U$, and $M_X^{(k)}(0)=\mathbb{E}[X^k]$.

Comment: This is not correct. Your $o(t)$ depends on $\omega$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for pointing out. Can you elaborate further and provide a valid approach for this ?

Comment: As of now I can only prove this when $0 \in U$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you provide an answer based on your argument? Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3228778/66096

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the case $U=(-r,r)$:  First note that $Ee^{t|X|} \leq E(e^{tX}+e^{-tX}) <\infty$ for $0< t <r$.  Let us show that $M_X$ is differentiable. Using similar argumnets and induction we can show that it is infinitely differentiable. Let $|t|<r$ and choose $u$ with $|t|<u<r$. Consider $M_X'(t)=\lim_{h \to 0}  E{e^{tX}}\frac {e^{hX-1}} h$. By MVT we get $ |{e^{tX}}\frac {e^{hX-1}} h| \leq |X| e^{u|X|}$ provided $|h| <u-|t|$. If we show that $E|X|e^{u|X|} <\infty $ it follows by DCT that $M_X$ is differentiable are $t$ and $M_X'(t)=EXe^{tX}$. Now pick $v$ such that $u <v<r$ and note that there exists a finite  constant $C$ such that $|x|e^{u|x|} \leq Ce^{v|x|}$ for all real numbers $x$. It follows that $E|X|e^{u|X|} <\infty $ so we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you provide more details on the following? 1) How do you apply MVT and why can you define such limit? 2) How to do induction on derivatives? 3) Can you extend the result to any open sets, not just $r$-neighborhood of $0$?